# Why can a SQL Server Password have a trailing space?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a login (SQL Server Authentication) and I was able to reproduce this. The password has a trailing space and I can log in to SSMS only if I provide the trailing space.

What's up with that?

Comment: you created login with password having trailing space?

Comment: So your question is *Why do I have to use the same exact password I created in order to log in?* Why would you expect behavior other than that? And not requiring exact matches on passwords would seem to be a pretty big security hole. *Gee, 6 out of the 7 characters match. Close enough.* doesn't seem to be a very good idea.

Comment: @KenWhite Obviously you don't understand the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, I understand the question perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Obviously you think you understand the question.

Comment: @Pinwar13 Yes. A password with a trailing space is accepted when I created the Login and I have to provide the trailing space when I log in to SSMS.

Comment: For your info,  blank password is also acceptable.

Comment: @Pinwar13 Excellent point. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, I understand the question. You created a password with a trailing space, and can't understand why you have to actually include that trailing space in order to successfully log in. Does that about cover it?

Comment: @KenWhite Not even close, but thanks anyway. You can have the last word.

Comment: That's not what you say in your question or [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691088/why-can-a-sql-server-password-have-a-trailing-space?noredirect=1#comment66683059_39691088), where you've stated exactly what I wrote in my summary.

Answer (score 3):

Because a space is as valid as any other character. There is no reason for it to be treated any other way.

Comment: Wacky, but seems true. What other system permits a space in a password? I love Microsoft.

Comment: I just don't see why you think spaces are special in this case. Passwords are not supposed to be known by anyone but the one who enters it so why would not supporting them be preferable?